# Writing Registry from VBA in 64-bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, registry

I use Chip Pearson's routines (www.cpearson.com/excel/registry.htm) to read and write registry values from Excel VBA program. They work on 32-bit Excel, but do not even compile on 64-bit Excel.

Today I found these https://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html. They work in 32-bit Excel, and on 64-bit Excel they compile ok and read the registry, but fail to write to registry or delete keys because of some access rights. I am running Excel as administrators, so I should have all the rights.

Is there a way to write registry values using VBA in 64-bit Excel?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe the problem is the declaration of Long data types.  You'll need to LongPtr instead of Long for 64-bit.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide sample code and the error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The code is given at www.cpearson.com/excel/registry.htm. When I try to compile in 64-bit Excel, the message is (at Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "..."): "The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit system. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute"